# I want to customize android numeric keyboard with background and colorful numbers

Tags: android, android-studio

This is how the numbers needs to look like. Can someone help me how I can achieve this.

[image: number]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use photoshop to design and follow this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html here is the code needed for implenting your button.

//Button_default means not pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Comment: feedback would have helped me too